# Tastypie decimal and datetime filters not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql, tastypie

The following **lte** and **gte** filter queries returns 0 objects:

```
curl http://localhost/river/river/?runoff__lte=100.0&runoff__gte=150.0
curl http://localhost/river/river/?runoff__lte=100&runoff__gte=150
http://localhost/river/river/?dt_timestamp__lte=2015-01-01T03:00&dt_timestamp__gte=2015-01-07T18:00&format=json
```

Here's **models.py**

```
class River(models.Model):
    dt_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    stage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    runoff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
```

**api.py**

```
class RiverResults(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = River.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'river'
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'dt_timestamp': ALL
            'stage': ALL,
            'runoff': ALL,
        }
```

In settings.py **USE_TZ = False**

Am running Postgresql **9.3**, Django **1.6** and  Tastypie **0.12.2**.
Not sure what am doing wrong.

Regards,
Allan

Answer (score 0):

I guess You need to select rivers where `runoff` are between 100 and 150 or `dt_timestamp` between 2015-01-01T03:00 and 2015-01-07T18:00. In this case try:

```
http://localhost/river/river/?runoff__gte=100.0&runoff__lte=150.0
http://localhost/river/river/?runoff__gte=100&runoff__lte=150
http://localhost/river/river/?dt_timestamp__gte=2015-01-01T03:00&dt_timestamp__lte=2015-01-07T18:00
```

If You need to select rivers where runoff are lower than 100 or greater than 150, then You need to overwrite `build_filters` function:

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    qs_filters = super(RiverResults, self).build_filters(filters)
    if filters.get('runoff_not_between') is not None:
        runoff_not_between = filters.get('runoff_not_between').split(',')
        qs_filters = qs_filters.update(Q(runoff__lte=runoff_not_between[0]) | Q(runoff__gte=runoff_not_between[1]))
    return qs_filters
```

and use:

```
http://localhost/river/river/?runoff_not_between=100.0,150.0
http://localhost/river/river/?runoff_not_between=100,150
```